# Load external JS that has document.write inside Angular partial

Tags: angularjs, jive

I am new to angular and we have a single page app built using angular. We want to have threaded discussions for every content we have. For this we are planning to integrate with Jive. Jive provides a way to embed discussions from jive on another site.

They just ask to include a js file and that automatically inserts a "Discussion" link in line on your site. Jive does it with the help of `document.write`.

If I include the js file in on our main app page it works. If i include the js file in one of partials it wont work and I get

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

I dont have access to change the js that is coming back from Jive.

How can i get around this?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a directive that creates script element.
Look at this answer
[How to write an AngularJS directive that creates DOM elements that are other directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107048/how-to-write-an-angularjs-directive-that-creates-dom-elements-that-are-other-dir)

I hope that helps...